# Optimize a Sql query: filter an unindexed field

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

I have a table `Orders` that stores orders, with fields:

```
Id          
Date        
Amount      
Cost
Currency
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount)-SUM(NFC1)
FROM Orders
WHERE Date BETWEEN '20121101' AND '20121231'
      AND Currency = 'EUR'
```

Now, according to Oracle SQL Developer, what makes the query slow is the `Currency = 'EUR'` filter, since the other operations have much lower cost.

I checked the indexes and I have an index on `Id`, and another index on `Date`.
It seems to me, by the query analysis, that the DBMS first finds the records matching the required dates and then scans the whole table to find the records having `Currency='EUR'`. `Currency` is a `VARCHAR`.

Is there any way to optimize the query? I mean, is there a way to avoid the full scan?

From a general point of view, is it possible to prevent the DBMS from performing a full table scan after records have already been filtered by date, but rather find the records that match the `Currency` among those who have already been filtered by date?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you show us the execution plan?

Comment: Oracle will obviously only scan through the subset of records that are left after applying of the previous filters.  1. Why do you think it is doing the full scan? 2. Why do you think it is filtering by dates first?

Comment: Show us the execution plan (posted as formatted text, not a screenshot)

Comment: Why do you store dates as strings? You should not do that.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems to me, by the query analysis, that the DBMS first finds the records matching the required dates and then scans the whole table to find the records having Currency='EUR'. Currency is a VARCHAR.

It does not scan the whole table.

Rather, it takes the row pointers (`rowid`'s or the `PRIMARY KEY` values if the table is an IOT) from the index records and looks up the currency in the table rows in a nested loop. Since the index you're using does not contain `Currency`, it needs to be looked up somehow to do the filtering.

To work around this, you would need to create a composite index on `(Currency, Date)`

If creating another index is not an option, you may try creating a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` and create an index on that.

Answer (score 0):

Build an index on a `Currency` field, or a compound index on `Date` and `Currency` if you often filter using both fields

Comment: Sorry but just out of curiosity what stops you from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to optimize the query? I mean, is there a way to avoid the full scan?

A full scan might just be the most optimized  plan available. Filtering data from a large portion of the table is usually faster by full scanning the table. The database can use fast, sequential disk reads.